# How do I run multiple SOAP calls simultaneously

Tags: php, multithreading, soap

I have multiple SOAP requests in my PHP application, which are being made to different servers. I would like for both requests to be received at the destination servers at a similar time (let's presume destination servers have the same latency). I also want to process the results from each call as soon as it gets back to me, without having to wait for both responses.

At the moment I have the following:

```
$firstServerResponse = $mySoapClient->getPrice($priceRequest); 
$secondServerResponse = $mySecondSoapClient->getPrice($priceRequest); 

//Processing of results
```

In this case, the call to the second SOAP server, and subsequent processing of the results will only be executed when the first response is received.

Is it possible in PHP to set a call back function, so I don't need to wait for both responses before I can process their respective results?

Comment: The SOAP call will be high frequency, so at the moment a possible solution may be two CRON jobs which will run two PHP scripts at the same time, each running a different SOAP call and writing the results to a DB. A third script could be executed to process the last set of results from the DB. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **threads** . See the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: This answer does not describe anything related to the question. It also might be difficult to install, as it needs a thread-safe PHP version, and the ability to install PECL extensions.